# Python to Bash Conversion?

Tags: bash, shell-script, python

***Problem:***

I came across a python program that was able to scan your network and tell you the hosts that are connected to it and / or kick unwanted users off your own network. It works well, but I'm not too familiar with Python syntax. I was just wondering if anyone with Python and Bash experience could tell me how to make something similar to the first part (Finding hosts on network and display them in a list) like this program does.

***Link to Program Overview (Github):***

https://github.com/k4m4/kickthemout

***Link to the Python Program Code (Github):***

https://github.com/k4m4/kickthemout/blob/master/kickthemout.py

Comment: 487 lines of code and you are just asking "how it works"?

Comment: Then link to *that part,* or excerpt it here.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already said how to implement this on shell script ( and perl ) on superuser:

[Superuser Version](https://superuser.com/questions/435356/a-pc-application-similar-to-wifikill-in-android)

And i found on github a full shell script version:

[Github Bash version](https://github.com/asdfMaciej/wifikill-linux)